# CCRenderTexture and threads warning on OS X

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, osx-mountain-lion

I am getting this warning with Cocos2D 2.0 on OS X:

-[CCRenderTexture initWithWidth:height:pixelFormat:depthStencilFormat:] : cocos2d: WARNING. CCRenderTexture is running on its own thread. Make sure that an OpenGL context is being used on this thread!

Here's the code that I believe is causing the warning:

```
- (id) initWithObject: (CCNode *) object mask: (CCSprite *) mask {
    NSAssert(object != nil, @"Invalid sprite for object");
    NSAssert(mask != nil, @"Invalid sprite for mask");

    if((self = [super init])) {

        _objectSprite = object;

        _maskSprite = mask;

        // Set up the burn sprite that will "knock out" parts of the darkness layer depending on the alpha value of the pixels in the image.
        [_maskSprite setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];

        // Get window size, we want masking over entire screen don't we?
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        // Create point with middle of screen
        CGPoint screenMid = ccp(size.width * 0.5f, size.height * 0.5f);

        // Create the rendureTextures for the mask
        _masked = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth: size.width height: size.height];

        [[_masked sprite] setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];

        // Set render textures at middle of screen
        _masked.position = screenMid;

        // Add the masked object to the screen
        [self addChild: _masked];

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAlphaBlending:YES];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Please help, I just cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

In `ccConfig.h`, find a line that says

`#define CC_DIRECTOR_MAC_THREAD CC_MAC_USE_DISPLAY_LINK_THREAD`

This is where the use of threads is defined. You can try using the main thread option (`CC_MAC_USE_MAIN_THREAD`), or use GCD to make sure all code is actually executed on `-[CCDirector runningThread]`. This will pretty much fix it.